# How to calculate the mean index in array with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, average

How can I calculate the mean index T for an array nums that minimize the value of

```
abs(sum(nums[:T])-sum(nums[T:]))
```

Comment: Produce a minimal sample data and expected output?

Comment: How can you even assume that's ever the case? `[1000, 2000, 3, 1]`, what's the `T` that works here? Also, this looks like a bad case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Thanks for the change. Still, looks a lot like the mentioned XY Problem. Anyway, what have you thought of so far? I'm sure you didn't first come here and ask the question, you certainly have some ideas, already, and it would be worth discussing them. What, for example, about having a helper variable that holds the running cumulative sum of `nums`?

Comment: In fact, I was to find a threshold in a histogram of a gray image with `np.average(range(0, 256), weights=histogram)` but failed, the result was not the mean index of the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem you're trying to solve has a well known solution called Otsu's method.  The code below is from https://learnopencv.com/otsu-thresholding-with-opencv/:

```
# Set total number of bins in the histogram
bins_num = 256

# Get the image histogram
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(image, bins=bins_num)

# Get normalized histogram if it is required
if is_normalized:
    hist = np.divide(hist.ravel(), hist.max())

# Calculate centers of bins
bin_mids = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2.

# Iterate over all thresholds (indices) and get the probabilities w1(t), w2(t)
weight1 = np.cumsum(hist)
weight2 = np.cumsum(hist[::-1])[::-1]

# Get the class means mu0(t)
mean1 = np.cumsum(hist * bin_mids) / weight1
# Get the class means mu1(t)
mean2 = (np.cumsum((hist * bin_mids)[::-1]) / weight2[::-1])[::-1]

inter_class_variance = weight1[:-1] * weight2[1:] * (mean1[:-1] - mean2[1:]) ** 2

# Maximize the inter_class_variance function val
index_of_max_val = np.argmax(inter_class_variance)

threshold = bin_mids[:-1][index_of_max_val]
print("Otsu's algorithm implementation thresholding result: ", threshold)
```

If you need to apply the threshold, it's even easier.  Adapted from https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html:

```
import cv2

image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0)
otsu_threshold, image_result = cv2.threshold(image_blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Depending on your needs, you may also want to look at adaptive thresholding, which is thresholding that is more localized to smaller regions within an image.

```
import cv2

image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image_blurred , 255,
    cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize=11, C=2)
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming it's a sorted array, because otherwise this doesn't make a lot of sense:

`numpy.searchsorted(nums, numpy.mean(nums))`

see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html